# WP-Query orderby rand with custom post type and custom taxonomy returns ordered output

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to pull up posts from a custom post type and a custom taxonomy.
I used the following query to achieve that:

```
$term_list = wp_get_post_terms($post->ID, 'influencers', array("fields" => "all"));
$the_query = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'influencer',
    'orderby' => 'rand',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
                'taxonomy' => 'influencers',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $term_list[0]->slug,
            )
        ),
    )
);
```

When i'm using $the_query->request

```
print_r($the_query->request);
```

to print the SQL i'm getting the following output:

```
SELECT wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1 AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (47329) ) AND wp_posts.post_type = 'influencer' AND ((wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY RAND()
```

Seems legit, right? I even went to the database itself and tried the query, it works perfectly with the randomization and returns the posts in a random order every time.

[image: First try with the query]
[image: Second try with the query]

But for some reason, when i'm trying to pluck the id's array:

```
$post_ids = wp_list_pluck( $the_query->posts, 'ID' );
print_r($post_ids);
```

I'm getting the array in the same order, every time:

```
Array ( [0] => 267133 [1] => 267137 [2] => 267139 [3] => 267141 [4] => 267143 )
```

When i'm trying to put the WP_Query in a loop:

```
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $the_query->the_post();
    //code to display loop
}
wp_reset_postdata();
```

It returns the posts in an organized order, every time as well.

Any idea how to make WP_Query to return the posts in randomized order, without applying outside functions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you don´t have Post Types Order plugin installed that might cause orderby=rand function not working. Also if you are running your site on WP Engine, it has been reported, that this function is disabled on server and needs to be enabled.

**EDIT:**
check [this site explaining where to find that option](http://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/docs/random-order-wpengine/), anyway this randomization is performance killer, but I think you realise that

Comment: I'm running on WP-Engine. What function does need to be enabled?

Comment: check [this site explaining where to find that option](http://wpexplorer-themes.com/total/docs/random-order-wpengine/), anyway this randomization is performance killer, but I think you realise that

Comment: Thanks, I needed it for a specific project, it works perfectly fine now :>